# Remove committed files from remote repo but keep them local

Tags: git, gitignore

I have some files in my central remote repository. I committed those in the past. They don't need to be tracked anymore. I add them to my .gitignore file. But I **still need** them in my local repo, for my local site.

What do I have to do, to get them out of my remote repository but still keep them in my local repository?

Answer (score 2):

[Edited]

you have to remove them from git with `git rm --cached foo.txt`. This will mark them as deleted in the repo, but not physically delete them.

So, here's a full print out :

```
master!git> git status
On branch master
nothing to commit, working directory clean
master!git> ls -la
total 0
drwxr-xr-x   4 creynder  staff   136 Apr 13 13:14 .
drwxr-xr-x@ 52 creynder  staff  1768 Apr 13 13:14 ..
drwxr-xr-x  12 creynder  staff   408 Apr 13 13:14 .git
-rw-r--r--   1 creynder  staff     0 Apr 13 13:14 foo.txt
master!git> git rm --cached foo.txt
rm 'foo.txt'
master!git *> git status
On branch master
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

    deleted:    foo.txt

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    foo.txt

master!git *> git commit -m 'Delete foo.txt'
```

Then add "foo.txt" to .gitignore.